# Lossless or near lossless compression options for PDFs containing grayscale with JPEG2000?

Tags: pdf, images, compression, adobe-acrobat, jpeg

I have some older books (pre 1900) that I'm working on archiving to a digital format. Most of the time using greyscale is satisfactory in terms of color preservation, however I'm having trouble with these books being too large. It just seems that Acrobat is not compressing things properly.

In particular, what has shocked me is that using JPEG2000 in Acrobat is a rather lossy process for even grayscale images.  The goal here, above all else, is to achieve low to no quality loss while simultaneously maximizing compression.

I went so far as to disable downsampling and to set the JPEG2000 compression quality to `Lossless`.

The only thing that has worked so far to preserve quality while having decent compression has been to use ZIP compression for grayscale and monochrome images, but even with this the compression doesn't seem to be as good as it should be with JPEG2000.

Another anomaly is that when I enable JPEG2000 for only the colored images, Acrobat still somehow manages to degrade grayscale pages.

What's going on here? Are there particularly special options that anyone has found that work well to use JPEG2000 for high quality output, particularly for greyscale?

Comment: How are you acquiring the image data? (scanner or camera?) What resolution / DPI are you using, and do you see acceptable results with compression disabled?

Comment: It's a book scanner with a resolution of 600 DPI. Yes, with compression processing off the PDF output quality is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> In particular, what has shocked me is that using JPEG2000 in Acrobat is a rather lossy process for even grayscale images.

The typical use of JPEG2000 (as well as for JPEG) compression is lossy compression. It is just a question of balancing your compression needs against your tolerance towards artefact creation.

I don't understand what you mean by saying: "Yes, with compression processing off the PDF output quality is acceptable." That sounds to me as if all problems are solved.

Please specify if you are bound by PDF as the final target file format.
What about a series of JPEG2000 files for instances instead?

What is your exact workflow like?

I would set the bookscanner to lossless output if available at its native resolution (600 dpi?).
Then I would test out the parameters for compression based on a page of your book scaner containing average noise and information density.

I have a simple commercial software called "Thumbs" that supports JPEG2000 encoding.
My total variables to influence quality would be dpi and jpeg2000 bitrate.
The jpeg2000 codec in Thumbs only has bitrate as a parameter, which can be varied between 0% and 100%.
I am not aware of the degree of freedom you have in your Acrobat version right now.

Please keep in mind that black words on white background reflect hard contrast, an issue neither JPEG or JPEG2000 handles well, they only differ in the look of compression artefacts.

If I remember correctly halving the resolution is bad, reducing the bitrate was better.

If you found a convenient set of parameters you would produce a jpeg2000-image for every tiff-image given in batch-mode.

If needed you would embed those pictures in a PDF container afterwards.